# Difference between mutableArrayValueForKey and calling insertObject:inEmployeesAtIndex: directly

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

I have a question regarding using KVO-compliant methods to insert/remove objects from an array. I'm working through Aaron Hillegass' Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X and I saw the following line of code (in the `insertObject:inEmployeesAtIndex:` method:

```
[[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:index];
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I always thought it was better to call `mutableArrayValueForKey:` and then `removeObjectAtIndex:`...so I tried changing the above line to this:

```
[[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:[self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"employees"]] removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

And it didn't work. Can someone explain the difference and why the first line works but the second line doesn't?

UPDATE: My removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:index method is implemented to make my collection class (an instance of NSMutableArray) KVC-compliant. So ultimately, calling `[[self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"employees"] removeObjectAtIndex:index];` should end up calling `[self removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:index];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update you say:

> calling [[self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"employees"] removeObjectAtIndex:index]; should end up calling [self removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:index];

Unfortunately this is not correct not matter what is in your `removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:` method as NSMutableArray will never call any methods in your class. Since you seem to be trying to get undo/redo functionality you have to use a method like `removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:`. Otherwise when you hit undo for adding an employee you will have no way to 'redo' adding that employee. You also could have issues with undo/redo for edits to individual employees. If you wanted to you could change the line in the `removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:` method that reads `[employees removeObjectAtIndex:index];` to `[[self valueForKey:@"employees"] removeObjectAtIndex:index];` or `[self.employees removeObjectAtIndex:index];` but there is really no reason to go this route.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The first line (from the book) is basically equivalent to this:

```
id tmp = [undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self];
[tmp removeObejctFromEmployeesAtIndex:index];
```

Your code, however, is basically equivalent to this:

```
id tmp1 = [self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"employees"];
id tmp2 = [undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:tmp1];
[tmp2 removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

In other words, the target that you're preparing the invocation with is different in your code (unless `self` happens to be the same object as `[self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"employees"]`, which is doubtful).

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion. I updated the post with some more detail. But actually, I do want to call -removeObjecAtIndex: on [self mutableArrayValueForKey:@employees"]